# Is there anyway to get random indexes of a list in a new list in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get indexes of a list store into a new list. 
for example,

```
A = ['A', 'B', 'C',....,'Z']
```

and B list will select random no of indexes of A list like.

```
B = [[2,None,None], [1,None,None], [3,None,None],.....,[0, None,None]]
```

where list limit is, suppose, 10 and None will be replaced with the random no between 0 to 20 and finally the list of resultant look like,

```
result = [[2, 2, 3], [0, 4, 5], [8, 2, 4], [3, 8, 9]]
```

the first element in a sublist refers to the list A and the 2nd and third elements refer to the random selection of numbers between 0 to 10

Comment: Any other requirements? For example, do the indices have to be distinct?

Comment: one more thing, if second value of each list in a condition that it only bring the random value from its previous column. let suppose, we have 3 columns and 3 rows and [1, 2, 3], [2,3,6],[0,3,5],....so on. let suppose these sublist is like gird of 3 * 3 and 1st sublist 1*1 in a gird and 2nd sublist is 1*2 in a gird and 3rd sublist is a 1*3 in a gird and 4th sublist is a 2*1 in a gird. where 1*1 mean 1st column and 2 row in a girl and so on. so every sublist 2nd and 3rd element should be its previous column random value. let me know if it make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

```
import random
result = [random.sample(range(len(A)), 1) + random.sample(range(10), 2) for _ in range(10) ]
```

Comment: Is it like a 3x3 matrix? and u want to get all the indexes?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind possible replication of values in the elements you can use a list comprehension, using [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) to generate the numbers:

```
result = [[random.randrange(26), random.randrange(10), random.randrange(10)] for _ in range(10)]
print(result)
```

Sample output:

```
[[18, 8, 1], [24, 1, 4], [24, 6, 5], [1, 4, 4], [7, 0, 9], [10, 7, 7], [0, 6, 9], [0, 9, 4], [6, 4, 4], [4, 2, 7]]
```

If you want to ensure no replication in each of elements of the list, you can use `zip` and [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to put together 3 lists of unique values and select values from those:

```
result = [[a, b, c] for a, b, c in zip(random.sample(range(26), 10), random.sample(range(10), 10), random.sample(range(10), 10))]
print(result)
```

Sample output:

```
[[2, 0, 1], [21, 4, 0], [11, 1, 4], [10, 7, 5], [15, 3, 3], [23, 6, 8], [25, 5, 2], [1, 9, 7], [24, 8, 9], [6, 2, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Think this basis for you

```
A = ['A', 'B', 'C','Z']
B = [[2,None,None], [1,None,None], [3,None,None],[0, None,None]]
for newb in B:
    if  newb[1] is None:
        newb[1] = random.randrange(0,10)
    if newb[2] is None:
        newb[2] = random.randrange(0,10)
print(B)
```

it do like

```
[[2, 2, 2], [1, 6, 9], [3, 5, 7], [0, 6, 2]]
```